# find b when $\frac{36^{3b}}{36^{2b}}=216^{2-b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find b when $\frac{36^{3b}}{36^{2b}}=216^{2-b}$. I got $b=\frac{12}{7}$ whereas my textbook says the solution is $\frac{6}{5}$

My working:

$$\frac{36^{3b}}{36^{2b}}=216^{2-b}$$
$$36^b=36^{6(2-b)}$$
$$b=6(2-b)$$
$$b=12-6b$$
$$7b=12$$
$$b=\frac{12}{7}$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $\frac{6}{5}$?

The online textbook is [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry@27.1/pages/6-6-exponential-and-logarithmic-equations). It's exercise 9 at the end of that page. The solution is [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/chapter-6) under section exercises for chapter 6.6, exercise 9.

Comment: $216\neq 36^6$.

Comment: Following lulu's comment, the remedy is to recognize that $(36)^b = 6^{(2b)}$ and that $(216)^{(2-b)} = 6^{[3(2-b)]}.$

Comment: I see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $216 = 6^3$,

Hence we have $$6^{2b}=6^{3(2-b)}$$

$$2b=3(2-b)$$

$$5b=6$$